# What is the ratio of Arabica and Robusta in blend coffees available in markets?

Tags: coffee-blends

I have seen some blend coffeees available in the market, both ground as well as instant.

I want to know what ratio is preferred normally while mixing Arabica and Robusta?

Country : India

Answer (score 2):

This is highly dependent on the market, I think. Still, based on my observations regarding corporate Italian espresso blenders, I would like to write a short answer.

If you purchase packaged coffee, which is not labeled as 100% Arabica, you are mostly buying from 10% to 30% Robusta.

Still, I would like to add, some quality Robusta's (especially Africans) may be superior to not so good Arabica's.

Again, the ratio of Robusta may go up to 50% in some house blends or horeca blends. You may even consume pure Robusta in Indonesia or in Vietnam.